# asp-net core2 new web projects issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create a new ASP-Net core2 MVC project, but the project is created with build errors

```
Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0).
```

And

```
Error   NU1202  Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
```

with a lot of NuGet packages compatibility issues as illustrated in the screenshot
[image]

I have  dotnet core2 installed, with Visual Studio version 15.3.0 and NuGet 4.1.0

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you have NuGet 4.1.0, because VS 2017 "15.3" should be shipped with NuGet 4.3.0.
I tried to create new project and have the same packages as you with no issues, but I have Nuget 4.3.0 installed.

Try to update your Nuget newer version, because for now only Nuget 4.3.0 has full support of Standard 2.0/.NET Core 2.0.

Comment: according to this https://www.nuget.org/downloads NuGet 4.1.0 is the recommended latest version, however, updating to NuGet 4.3.0 fixed my issue, thank you